# How can I obtain a unit vector of a shifted spherical system?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I hope that I can explain myself clear enough, Assuming I have a sphere that has been moved down in the $Z$-axis. I know that r unit vector when the sphere is not shifted can be expressed as:
$x\,\sin\theta\,\cos\varphi+y\,\sin\theta\,\sin\varphi+z\,\cos\theta$
where $x,y,z $ and the cartesian unit vectors. But how can I obtain r unit vector over the surface of the sphere in a situation when the sphere has been shifted? like in the picture i added?[image]

Comment: If I understood you correctly, $\vec u = (\sin\theta\cos\phi,\, \sin\theta\sin\phi, a + \cos\theta)$ where $a$ is shift

Comment: And then to make it a unit vector all i need is to normalize? and how can i derive this unit vector by math? logiclly of course it makes sense, but what about $\theta$ unit vector for example? how can I derive it?